# Intel icc breaks gcc with math.h on linux

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, gcc, icc

I installed Intel's compilers and applications bundled with their Parallel Studio the other day and I cannot compile without using icc. When using gcc, clang or mpicc, I get the following error:

```
In file included from z.main.c:13:0:
/opt/intel/include/math.h:29:3: error: #error "This Intel <math.h> is for
use with only the Intel compilers!"
# error "This Intel <math.h> is for use with only the Intel compilers!"
   ^
  main
```

Normally I have to link to the `math.h` library with `-lm`, and this works with other files. The other cases I've tested do not include `mpi.h`, if it matters.

I don't care to uninstall the intel compilers; I was hoping to fix whatever problems I have locally before moving to working remotely via ssh.

**Update**

I ran `gcc fvm.c -c --trace -lm` to see where it was looking for the math library. Here is the result:

```
gcc z.fvm.c -c --trace -lm
. /usr/include/stdio.h
.. /usr/include/features.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
.. /opt/intel/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h
.. /usr/include/libio.h
... /usr/include/_G_config.h
.... /opt/intel/include/stddef.h
.... /usr/include/wchar.h
... /opt/intel/include/stdarg.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h
. /usr/include/stdlib.h
.. /opt/intel/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitflags.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h
... /usr/include/endian.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/endian.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap-16.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h
... /usr/include/time.h
... /opt/intel/include/stddef.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/select.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigset.h
.... /usr/include/time.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysmacros.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
.. /usr/include/alloca.h
... /opt/intel/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib-float.h
. /opt/intel/include/math.h
.. /usr/include/math.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_valf.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_vall.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/inf.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/nan.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathdef.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h
In file included from fvm.c:10:0:
/opt/intel/include/math.h:29:3: error: #error "This Intel <math.h> is for
use with only the Intel compilers!"
# error "This Intel <math.h> is for use with only the Intel compilers!"
   ^
. /usr/include/time.h
.. /opt/intel/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h
.. /usr/include/xlocale.h
. fvm.h
. lab_mpi.h
Multiple include guards may be useful for:
/usr/include/wchar.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap-16.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/endian.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_valf.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_vall.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/inf.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathdef.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/nan.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/select.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigset.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib-float.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitflags.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
fvm.h
lab_mpi.h
```

How can I tell gcc, mpicc where to look and ignore the Intel math library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide the gcc command you are using which indicates to NOT use the math.h in the `/Intel/include/` folder.    If your OS has system variables comment out the Intel variable.

Comment: Ok, after further investigating, the icc compiler only works in one directory. How can I either make it accessible from everywhere, or just restore my working gcc, mpicc... ?

Comment: Modify all .h and .c files to use `/usr/include/math.h` instead of `/opt/intel/include/math.h`

Answer (score 0):

Intel header are compatible, but a small modification is required.
First, you need to turn off the source of the error.

```
//#if !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
//# error "This Intel <math.h> is for use with only the Intel compilers!"
//#endif
```

Then you should include missing headers.

```
#include <features.h>
```